# Counting characters in a text file

Tags: java

I have a text file and I was curious about what character appears how often in the text.

Any review is appreciated.

```
public class CountLetters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TreeMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
        File file = new File("C:/text.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file,"utf-8");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            for (Character c : chars) {
                if(!Character.isLetter(c)){
                    continue;
                }
                else if (hashMap.containsKey(c)) {
                    hashMap.put(c, hashMap.get(c) + 1);
                } else {
                    hashMap.put(c, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be for example:

> ```
> a: 1202
> b: 311
> c: 603
> d: 510
> e: 2125
> f: 373
> g: 362
> h: 718
> i: 1313
> j: 5
> k: 74
> l: 678
> m: 332
> n: 1129
> o: 1173
> p: 348
> q: 40
> r: 812
> s: 1304
> t: 1893
> u: 415
> v: 195
> w: 314
> x: 86
> y: 209
> z: 9
> ```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Resources:

You should start using [`try-with-resources`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) This statment does some work for you with resources that implement `AutoCloseable`. It closes these resources for you, so you don't have to worry about file-locks and remaining database connections:

```
File file = new File("C:/text.txt");
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, "utf-8")){
    //your code here ;)
}
```

You also shouldn't throw `Exception` in the main method of your program. This can be very confusing to users. Instead you main-method should handle all exceptions "gracefully" by being wrapped into a [try-catch-block.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

#### Conditionals:

> ```
> if(!Character.isLetter(c)){
>    continue;
> }
> ```

This is an early return statement for the purpose of following conditions, meaning you don't have to write `else if` in your next condition.

#### Naming

`hashMap` is not a good name. The map you use is not a Hash-Map, and `treeMap` would also not explain what the map does, what it *contains*.

You might want to rename it to `characterMap`

all else equal, your naming is nice and consistent, and tells exactly what the variables do. You nicely follow `camelCase`-conventions. **Keep it up!**

#### Summary:

Your code reads nicely and is easily understandable. You follow naming conventions and have descriptive and understandable variable names. You should work on your exception handling and the use of resources.

Comment: I would name it `characters` instead of `characterMap` since that "map" doesn't add anything and instead removes some abstraction from your variable. It will cause a refactoring if you change the underlying datastructure.

Comment: @Jeroen ypu have a point. But changing the underlying datastructure will cause a refactoring either way.

Comment: I would use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` rather than the `String`. Otherwise +1

Comment: @BoristheSpider In this case it would require `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()` not just `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.

Answer (score 8):

My notes in code:

```
public class CountLetters {
    // Throwing Exception is too general, you should throw IOException
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // It is better practice to define Map, instead of TreeMap
        // The name of variable hashMap could be better, for example characterMap or characters
        TreeMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
        File file = new File("C:/text.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file,"utf-8");

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
            for (Character c : chars) {
                if(!Character.isLetter(c)){
                    // 'continue' is unnecessary as last statement in a loop
                    // It is better to put following 'else if' and 'else' here and to remove negation in condition
                    // like this: if(Character.isLetter(c)){ if ( ... ) { ... } else { ... } }
                    continue;
                }
                else if (hashMap.containsKey(c)) {
                    hashMap.put(c, hashMap.get(c) + 1);
                } else {
                    hashMap.put(c, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        // You should call scanner.close() here

        // I would wrap this into if (!hashMap.isEmpty()) { ... }, but it is not really needed
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I would rewrite the class like this:

```
public class CountLetters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<Character, Integer> characters = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/text.txt"),"utf-8");

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                char[] line = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();

                for (Character character : line) {
                    if (Character.isLetter(character)){
                        if (characters.containsKey(character)) {
                            characters.put(character, characters.get(character) + 1);
                        } else {
                            characters.put(character, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (scanner != null){
                scanner.close();
            }
        }

        if (!characters.isEmpty()){
            for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : characters.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's great to see such a new user being so active!  +1, and feel free to join us in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) sometime! :)

Answer (score 8):

1. I would change the map `hashMap` to `characterCounterMap`.
2. Then I would initialized the map at first with characters, like

   ```
   for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
       characterCounterMap.put(c,0);
   }
   ```
3. Then it will help you to shortening the if-else ladder, like

   ```
   if(Character.isLetter(character)) {
       characterCounterMap.put(character, characterCounterMap.get(character) + 1);
   } // see no else
   ```

Comment: Caution! [`Character.isLetter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter\(char\)) is Unicode-aware, and supports more than just 'a'..'z'.

Answer (score 8):

All the points in Vogel612's answer should be taken into consideration. Your failure to close resources is your biggest issue.

My main aim with this answer is to show how how this *should* now be done with Java 8.

Your current method uses very traditional Java loops and conditions. Here is how the code should look with the Java 8 APIs:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Path file = Paths.get("C:/text.txt");
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file)) {
        final Map<Character, Integer> count = lines.
                flatMap(line -> IntStream.range(0, line.length()).mapToObj(line::charAt)).
                filter(Character::isLetter).
                map(Character::toLowerCase).
                collect(TreeMap::new, (m, c) -> m.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum), Map::putAll);
        count.forEach((letter, c) -> System.out.println(letter + ": " + c));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read file.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

This code has exactly the same function as your code but is significantly shorter - it leverages Java 8's new `Stream` API combined with the all new lambdas.

The code uses `Files.lines` to get a `Stream<String>` consisting of each line. It then uses `flatMap` to turn that into a `Stream<Character>` by "flattening" a `Stream<Stream<Character>>` which we get by creating an `IntStream` of `[0, line.length())` and calling `line.charAt` for each element of the `IntStream`. The `char` is then autoboxed to a `Character`.

We use the `filter` method of `Stream` to strip out things that aren't letters.

Now we use the new `Map.merge` method with takes a key and a value and in addition a lambda that takes two values. If the key does not exist in the map then it is simply added with the given value. If it does exist in the map then the lambda is called with the existing value and the new value; the value returned from the lambda is then put into the map.

We use the `collect` method of the `Stream<Character>` to "reduce" the stream to a mutable collection, in this case a `TreeMap`.

Finally we use the new `forEach` method on `Map` to print out the contents of the map.

As a demonstration of the power of Java 8, in order to sort the output by count rather than by the character (as you had in your post), simply change the print to:

```
count.entrySet().stream().
        sorted((l, r) -> l.getValue().compareTo(r.getValue())).
        forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue()));
```

Comment: This is really a nice rewrite to Java 8.

Comment: Something I just noticed... what's the reason you're flatmapping over an IntStream that calls into charAt instead of using `Arrays.stream` onto toCharArray? `flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.toCharArray())` should work just as well and is IMO cleaner...

Comment: @Vogel612 you may have a point - I remember having lots of issues with `char` and `int` and boxing/unboxing; the only downside I can see from using `toCharArray` is that it creates a new `char[]` - but creating the new `InterStream` might well be even worse. Another issue I spotted, now that I'm looking at it, is that in the last part `(l, r) -> l.getValue().compareTo(r.getValue())` could simply be [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--).

Comment: `but is significantly shorter` I see that you consider this to be an advantage, but I do not believe shorter code is always _better_ . To me it is usually more difficult to read, to runtime it does not matter at all anyway.. So where is the advantage?

Comment: @KorayTugay I believe it is only more difficult to use because you are not used to reading it. I think the above Java 8 code is more terse and expresses semantic meaning much better - you read what the _intent_ of the code is rather than all the boilerplate around the code.

Comment: Instead of `charAt`, real Java 8 programs should use `String.codePoints`.

Comment: @RolandIllig not neccessary in this case. It's not a question is always looking at code points, it's a question of what you want to do with the data. If you then need to convert to a `Character` in, order to check `isLetter` for example, then you are better off with a `char`.

Comment: `isLetter` has a variant taking an `int`, because the `char` type can only represent a small subset of all possible Unicode code points. To support code points outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, the code should operate on code points, not on `uint16`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         TreeMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
> ```

In Java, we prefer types to be interfaces rather than implementations.  In this case, the interface could be `Map`, but

```
        SortedMap<Character, Integer> characterCounts = new TreeMap<>();
```

I think that you actually want `SortedMap`, as otherwise there is no need to use a `TreeMap`.  You could even use `NavigableMap`, although you don't seem to be using that functionality.

In modern Java versions, you don't need to specify the types in `<>` twice.  The compiler will match the second to the first automatically.

I changed the name to `characterCounts`, as that better describes the data that it holds.

> ```
>                 if(!Character.isLetter(c)){
>                     continue;
>                 }
>                 else if (hashMap.containsKey(c)) {
>                     hashMap.put(c, hashMap.get(c) + 1);
>                 } else {
>                     hashMap.put(c, 1);
>                 }
> ```

Since you continue in the first clause, you don't need an `else`.  You can instead say something like

```
                if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
                    continue;
                }

                Integer count = characterCounts.get(c);
                if (count == null) {
                    count = 0;
                }

                count++;
                characterCounts.put(c, count);
```

Now we don't have two `put` statements.  And we don't call `contains` explicitly just to call `get`, which calls `contains` implicitly.  We simply treat a null count as if it were zero.  The rest of our logic is the same in both paths.

I find the explicit increment easier to read than adding one.

I added some whitespace for readability.